Create an indicator for whether an event occurred within 6 months before for the same ID
I have something like this:
ID       Visit_Date        VISIT TYPE

001       JAN032000         OFFICE        
001       DEC141999         SURGERY       
001       FEB082002         OFFICE        
002       JUN272000         OFFICE        
002       APR142003         OFFICE        
003       MAR292000         SURGERY       
004       DEC072001         SURGERY       
004       FEB142002         OFFICE        


I want to create a column that indicates whether each patient had a surgery up to 6 months before each office visit:
ID       Visit_Date        VISIT TYPE    SX_6MO_B4_VISIT

001       JAN032000         OFFICE        1
001       DEC141999         SURGERY       NA
001       FEB082002         OFFICE        0
002       JUN272000         OFFICE        0
002       APR142003         OFFICE        0
003       MAR292000         SURGERY       NA 
004       DEC072001         SURGERY       NA
004       FEB142002         OFFICE        1


I am trying solutions like this, but I'm getting an error that the DateDiff function cannot be located. Any ideas greatly appreciated!
PROC SQL;
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN EXISTS
(SELECT 1 FROM DATA D2 
WHERE D2.ID=D.ID AND
D2.VISIT_TYPE= "SURGERY" AND
AND D.VISIT_TYPE = "OFFICE" AND 
DATEDIFF(MM,D2.VISIT_DATE D.VISIT_DATE) <=6 )
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS SX_6MO_B4_VISIT
FROM DATA D;
QUIT;


The equivalent function to DATEDIFF in SAS is called INTCK - however it may not be a straight swap: https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p1md4mx2crzfaqn14va8kt7qvfhr.htm

You did not have all the commas in your DateDiff parameters DATEDIFF(MM, D2.VISIT_DATE, D.VISIT_DATE).  Try this:
SELECT *,
   CASE WHEN EXISTS
        (SELECT 1 FROM Data D2 
        WHERE D2.ID=D.ID 
            AND D2.visit_type = 'SURGERY' 
            AND D.visit_type = 'OFFICE' 
            AND DATEDIFF(MM, D2.VISIT_DATE, D.VISIT_DATE) <=6 )
     THEN 1 ELSE 0 
   END AS SX_6MO_B4_VISIT
FROM Data D;

